# jQuery Replace Part of URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Vimeo URL that looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/57418480?byline=0&portrait=0&autoplay=1" width="620" height="350" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

What I want to do is take the video ID, which in this case is 57418480 and replace it onclick. I would have the ID set via the class attribute. For example:

```
<li><a href="#" class="57418481">Ethics in Investing</a></li>
```

Clicking the above link would replace just the number ID, so it would then look like this:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/57418481?byline=0&portrait=0&autoplay=1" width="620" height="350" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var newID = $(this).attr('class');
    var newURL = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + newID + '?byline=0&portrait=0&autoplay=1';
    $('iframe').attr('src',newURL);
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Khpd7/

Answer (score 2):

Use data-url in your link

```
<li><a href="#" data-url="https://player.vimeo.com/video/57418481?byline=0&portrait=0&autoplay=1" class="57418481">Ethics in Investing</a></li>
```

**onclick:**

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
  $('iframe').attr('src',$(this).data('url'));
});
```

Comment: This is actually a better way of approaching the problem.Thanks for your answer, it worked great! :)